# How to scroll to the main component on backpress in Next JS using Links?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-link

Here is what I want to achieve. I have few components that I have embedded in my layout. The sidebar is component is mapping through the Links to display links. When i click on the link, I move to that component on the same page. From there if i click on other component a few time, on pressing back button, I follow the whole breadcrumb of how I reached to that component. I've tried setting scroll behavior to true, which is its default value, but nothing seems to be working. Here is the code.

```
"use client"
import React from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { IconProp } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import Link from "next/link";
import BackToDefault from '@/components/default';

type MyComponentProps = {
  name: string;
  icon: IconProp;
  link: string;
  // Add more props as needed
};

const NavLinks = (props:MyComponentProps) => {

  return (
    <Link href={props.link} scroll={true} >
    <div  className="flex w-full h-10 group pl-2 hover:cursor-pointer  hover:bg-gray-300 items-center relative transition-transform duration-300 hover:transform hover:scale-95 hover:shadow-lg">
    {/* Hidden div */}
    <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-[2px] h-full  bg-blue-500 opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 transition-opacity duration-300"></div>
  
    {/* Icon */}
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={props.icon} className=" w-1/4 flex justify-end " style={{ fontSize: '1.5em', color: 'rgb(59 130 246)'  }} />
   
    {/* Text */}
    <span className=" text-sm  ml-2 text-black">{props.name}</span>
     
   </div>
   
   </Link>
  )
}

export default NavLinks
```